# Change a UIImage using UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextinput

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uialertview

i am trying to create some kind of loyalty card in my application, basically when the right password is entered i want it to change the image of the UIImageView, but i cannot get it to work, here is some code:

```
@synthesize imageView;

- (IBAction)Stamp:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SECRET CODE"    message:@"Please hand your device to the business representative who will stamp your card" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"STAMP", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
[alert show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex)
{
    UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

    NSString *s1 = @"stamp";

    if (textfield.text == s1)
    {
        UIImage * Stampit = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1Stamp@2x" ofType:@"png"]];
        [imageView setImage:Stampit];

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: use `testfield.text isEqual:@"stamp"` or `isEqualToString:S1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be comparing strings using the reference equality (`==`) operator. Instead, use the `isEqualToString:` method of `NSString` like so:

```
NSString *s1 = @"stamp";
if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:s1]) {
    ...
```

Using `==` will determine whether the `NSString` instance referred to by `textfield.text` and the `NSString` instance referred to by `s1` are the *same object*, meaning both variables point to the same address in memory.

This is *not* how you want to compare strings - rather, you'd like to have the individual characters compared, ensure they're of the same case, etc. This is what `isEqualToString:` will do for you.

Comment: Thank You! i always mess up on the simplest things